# Java testing framework

Tags: java, testing, frameworks

I have to write an automated script in Java to do following

1. Login to an internal website with userid and password
2. Once login is complete click on a link which will open another web application and make sure the website is available
3. Send success / failure email to a specified group

The above job will have to run every day at a specified time to check the site availability. (I can use windows scheduler to schedule this as a job)

Due to network policy I cannot use any site availability websites to check this.

There are lot of Java based test frameworks available in market.

I would appreciate if anyone can point me to the right framework.

Thanks

Comment: Have you searched? You would have found Selenium...

Answer (score 2):

Selenium Web-Driver Automation framework is the best. It supports multiple langugaes, along with Java. You can check the seleniumorg site http://seleniumhq.org/

For mailing, you can use Java Mail API.